# Not flying the first leg of the journey – Company cancels the second-leg ticket

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, iberia

I've a friend that booked a round-trip journey. He booked *A*-to-*B* and *B*-to-*A*.
Somehow he needed to be earlier at location *B*, so he took a train and did not take the flight from *A* to *B*.

When he went to the airport to take the "back home" flight (*B*-to-*A*), he was informed that his ticket was canceled because he did not take the *A*-to-*B* flight. They canceled the ticket and sold it to someone else.

Is this normal? The company said it was their right to do so, and he could not get the flight back.
The company was Iberia.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18854/is-it-okay-to-board-only-the-second-flight-of-a-return-ticket-the-return-ticket) can answer your question partially.

Comment: Did you check-in for either or both of the legs?

Comment: I can't remember, it was quite some time ago and it didn't happen to me but to a friend.

Comment: That is neither uncommon, nor in any way reasonable.

Which matters more to you?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes. It is usually required that you fly all legs of a single ticket. Even if you skip the last leg, the airline might penalise you later. At the very least, you should contact the airline before the flight and tell them that for unforeseen reasons you need to skip one leg; in this case, they *might* not cancel the remainder.

Of course, in every particular case it depends on the fine print of your ticket. As Burhan Khalid points out, this probably just refers you to the policy of the carrier, for example:

> The General Terms and Conditions of Carriage of [airline] apply. They are to be found on [airline's website] and can be provided at all [airline] ticket counters.

In the case of Iberia, I cannot find the relevant section in their [Conditions of Carriage](http://www.iberia.com/bills/conditions/), so your friend might actually have a case against them (but more likely I am missing something).

As an example, another airline has

> In as much a Ticket was booked that requires the observance of a predetermined chronological order of the 
>   use of the individual Flight Coupons, and the Passenger deviates from this chronological order, the Airline will 
>   charge the price that would have applied at the time of booking the actual route taken.

In other words, if you don't fly the route on your ticket, the airline can charge you for the route you did actually fly.

Comment: When you say: "Even if you skip the last leg, the airline might penalise you later" are you saying that if I don't take the return flight I can be penalised? How?

Comment: I have heard rumours of airlines refusing to sell people tickets after they did this many times.

Comment: @Max, why in the world they could do that?

Comment: _"the fine print of your ticket"_ I think this is better stated as _"the policies of your carrier"_.

Comment: @user626528 ticket prices are not simply cost of flying plus some profit percentage; they are carefully structured depending on demand. Therefore, it's important to the airline's profit that you don't do things like use return tickets as singles. If they decide you're not worth the cost, they won't fly you any more.

Comment: @Max: They are not losing, maybe even saving some money if they are paid for two flights (even if those are discount prices due to the round trip), but only one gets used. So, again, why in the world would they do that? Of course, assuming the first leg is simply *not taken* by the customer, rather than cancelled with a refund.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper they are losing money compared to you buying the more expensive one-way ticket (if the one-way ticket is cheaper, they probably won't do that; I'm only saying it's *possible*, not that it always happens)

Comment: @Max: Oh, ok. Finding a pretext for why a customer could have paid more and then charging that definitely is a popular method to trick customers into having to pay more than for the original offer. Then I understand; thanks for your explanation :-)

Comment: @Max Yes, the reason is to penalize you for using double-way tickets as one-way (which BTW people do only because the _same_ outbound flight can become enormously cheaper by simply attaching a return to it, which is ridiculous to say the least). This is why airlines _want_ to do that. But the question is why they _are allowed_ to do that by the law.

Answer (score 11):

This is normal. Most airlines, if you tell them about your change in itinerary, will tell you that they won't cancel your remaining flights and it's all taken care of. However, I have always had the remainder of my flights cancelled no matter what they say, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Most important is that you contact the airline. If A-B wasn't taken, there should be a way to confirm why and that you'll take B-A anyway. Some airlines are strict and try to charge more for everything while others are easy and nice. Check the fine print when you buy the ticket.