# Can I skip the first part of a stop over?

Tags: airlines, bookings

I have flight booking

SIN - KUL(stopover) - CDG

Its on December 17. SIN - KUL is at 11am, Paris flight is 11pm so almost an 11 hour stopover.

Now I'm booking another flight. MLE-KUL(stopover)-SIN.

It lands in KUL December 17th 6am.

So now my question is can I skip the KUL-SIN part of my MLE-JUL-SIN journey thereby also skipping the SIN-KUL part of my SIN-KUL-CDG flight.

*Its Malaysian Airlines
*Its booked this way because the alternative routes are very expensive even if i picked the same exact flights.

Comment: i saw that. but in my case i have enuf time to check in before the first leg of my SIN-KUL-SIN begins. only thing is i will be in KUL then

Comment: The check in is not important. You can skip the KUL-SIN part of your MLE-KUL-SIN journey. That's fine. I assume it's one way. Your ticket dies as soon as you don't show up. However, if you don't show up for your SIN-KUL flight on the SIN-KUL-CDG ticket, then that ticket dies as well and you don't get to fly to Paris. The airline didn't price it by accident. The airline works very hard to get the prices right for every journey it sells. The airline won't allow you to undermine its pricing strategy like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not really.**

You can skip the KUL-SIN leg of your inbound flight from MLE, since it's the last leg.

However, if you don't show up for SIN-KUL, [your KUL-CDG flight will also be cancelled](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27355/not-flying-the-first-leg-of-the-journey-company-cancels-the-second-leg-ticket).  And no, you will not be allowed to check-in for KUL-CDG directly, precisely because they don't want people to do this kind of thing.

Comment: SIN-KUL-CDG begins 11am. i will be in KUL by 6am. so is it possible to check in via KUL counters for the latter leg.?

Comment: @JinahAdam You can if you want, but you still need to fly the SIN-KUL leg. If you do not, the airline will cancel the rest of your ticket.