# Skip first leg of Greyhound journey

Tags: usa, public-transport, buses, greyhound

When travelling a (US) Greyhound service including a transfer, is it possible to skip the first leg of the journey? For flight tickets [we know](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27355/not-flying-the-first-leg-of-the-journey-company-cancels-the-second-leg-ticket) that this is generally not allowed. But does Greyhound consider it as two distinct bookings or is it one indivisible whole?

Comment: Do you have a single ticket and travelling a route which has one, or more, stops?

Comment: @Dorothy I don't have a ticket yet but intend to buy one for a journey with multiple stops and then a transfer to an Express service without stops. The part until the transfer is where I'm not sure if I will take it.

Comment: If your tickets are separate, the second non-stop bus shouldn't be affected. If you no-show the first part of a continuous ticket, you may not be able to board at a later stop without presenting the unused ticket at a Greyhound depot counter. You would be better to get the advice from Greyound customer service in advance of booking, and ask for the best way and best price to do what you want.

Comment: @Dorothy But with separate tickets I'm afraid about what happens if the first bus is delayed and I miss the connection.

Comment: Greyhound will print a racket for each bus.  I've never tried this, but if you figured out another way to get to the starting point of the second ticket, I suspect you could show it to the driver and board without showing the unused first ticket.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: Book everything at the same time with Greyhound, and it will honor the tickets, even if you miss a connection and have to catch the next one. Make sure you read the Terms & Conditions in advance; it may require a more expensive, more flexible series of tickets. If you're on a delayed bus, Greyhound will accommodate you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Over at Busbud we sell a lot of Greyhound tickets. My understanding is this will maybe work in practice but you shouldn't expect it to or count on it.

It's been hard for Greyhound to have a good idea of which passengers actually show up in real-time because the drivers have validated paper tickets by hand. This is still true in many cases.

However, Greyhound is currently in the process of rolling out electronic ticket scanning. This lets them see who didn't show up to the bus and allows them resell that seat further down the line - it's part of a larger project to be more aggressive on pricing to meet demand similar to airlines.

So especially if your first bus happens to have electronic ticket scanning and the second bus happens to be popular and sold out you might have problems getting them to accept your ticket.

Some tickets are indeed refundable and changeable, these could also serve your purpose. Don't expect your seat to be held if you miss the first section though in case the bus is sold-out. You have your ticket rebooked in this case, so the system doesn't log you as a no-show and allow your seat to be resold.